# Insufficient Memory Exception in WCF Large File Uploading

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, wcf, memory

I am trying to upload large files(>10GB) using WCF. 
The Service Web.config is as below

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647000000" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
     maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:42890/Service1.svc"  behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    contract="UploadFileService.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding"  />
</client>
```

And the client side web.config as below

```
   <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00"
      receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647000000" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I got insufficient memory exception when I run the code, How can I solve it?

Comment: Perhaps it is time to rethink your solution and not send 10GB in a single message?  That or think about adding `Stream`ing to your service https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, target x64 instead of Any CPU. This will allow more memory allocation.

However, depending on your solution, you might be able to `Stream` the file to disk, not requiring to use so much memory.

Comment: I guess it is a problem about web.config, but I cant figure out. @AndreAndersen